# not able to write bold characters using textbf

Tags: r, latex, bold

I'm working in LaTeX and R and I am using UTF-8 encoding, but when I use `\textbf{dataset}`, the resulting text is not bold.

Can someone tell me why this happens?

Below is part of my code. I am not sure what the reason behind it is.

```
\documentclass[11pt,table,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
   cat("dataset","\n")
   cat("\\textbf{dataset}","\n")   # it should be bold  
@
\end{document}linecolor=goldenpoppy
```

The error is due to `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`. Please help me out in fixing this problem.

Comment: If you don't get your issue solved in StackOverflow, you might want to try its sister site, [tex.se]. No need to cross-post there though, just flag your question as off-topic, and the moderators will migrate the question soon after.

Comment: ... although, after having a look at your profile, you seem to be quite aware of the existence of tex.se :)

Comment: I m not aware that same people respond on stackoverflow. I thought it is different site so posting my questions on different sites to get solution of my pblm as soon as possible.

Comment: Please don't cross-post! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: It seems that you should be able to boil this down to a MWE for the TeX site by taking the LaTeX code produced by Sweave and experimenting with it ... if it works with `\usepackage{Sweave}` commented out, then it is a pure LaTeX problem of some sort.  If it succeeds, then it's an interaction between `Sweave.sty` and your other LaTeX code ...

Comment: Yes, if i comment \usepackage{Sweave}, then it works well for me. There is interaction between Sweave.Sty and Latex code. How can i solve this pblm?

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding `Sweave` package with the `noae` option would fix this:

```
\usepackage[noae]{Sweave}
```